# Sha256 in Objective-C for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, hash, sha256

When I use this code to create a sha256 of a string

```
unsigned char hashedChars[32];
NSString *inputString;
inputString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello"];
NSData * inputData = [inputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
CC_SHA256(inputData.bytes, inputData.length, hashedChars);
```

It returns the hash correctly, but I need to insert a string like this **\x00\x25\x53** and in this case, the function returns a sha256 of empty string because the specified encoding cannot be used to convert the receiver.

Now, my question is:How to insert this special characters for generate a correct hash? Thanks

Answer (score 42):

Try this, it worked for me

1) To get a hash for plain text input

```
-(NSString*)sha256HashFor:(NSString*)input
{   
    const char* str = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA256(str, strlen(str), result);

    NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
    for(int i = 0; i<CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

2) To get hash for `NSData` as input

**Note:-** I have used `NSData` category, so the code is as follow

```
    - (NSString *)SHA256_HASH {
    //if (!self) return nil;

    unsigned char hash[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    if ( CC_SHA256([(NSData*)self bytes], [(NSData*)self length], hash) ) {
        NSData *sha2 = [NSData dataWithBytes:hash length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH]; 

        // description converts to hex but puts <> around it and spaces every 4 bytes
        NSString *hash = [sha2 description];
        hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
        hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
        // hash is now a string with just the 40char hash value in it
        //NSLog(@"hash = %@",hash);

        // Format SHA256 fingerprint like
        // 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
        int keyLength=[hash length];
        NSString *formattedKey = @"";
        for (int i=0; i<keyLength; i+=2) {
            NSString *substr=[hash substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 2)];
            if (i!=keyLength-2) 
                substr=[substr stringByAppendingString:@":"];
            formattedKey = [formattedKey stringByAppendingString:substr];
        }

        return formattedKey;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: How to make a hash for special characters like "Lähettäjä:" ??

Comment: Thanks for it! First one is working with special characters too!

Comment: Slight remark, what is the `if (!self)` for? If the instance is `nil`, the signal will never get to this method, right?

Comment: how can i use this with a key  , with a key and a string ?

Comment: @Mr.G didn't get you how exactly you want to use the SHA alg. But if it the encryption you are looking for then this doesn't help you.

Comment: @Jagadeeshwar its like this  same as hash_init('sha256',HASH_HMAC,$salt);hash_update($hash,$plain_hash);  in php want to do the same functionality in iOS

Comment: What's CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH? Got it - need to `#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>`

Comment: If you're getting the implicit conversion error you need to change the line to this `CC_SHA256(str, (CC_LONG)strlen(str), result);`

Answer (score 2):

It's important to know that you need to import:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use `NSData` instead of `NSString` then. Where do you get that string from?

Comment: My cycle trasform for example this string "002553" in "\x00\x25\x53" and i would send this bytes to the sha256 function for create the hash, but i have problem with encoding obviously!

Answer (score 0):

Some one looking the solution in Swift 3.0. here is

```
extension String {

// MARK: - SHA256
func get_sha256_String() -> String {
    guard let data = self.data(using: .utf8) else {
        print("Data not available")
        return ""
    }
    return getHexString(fromData: digest(input: data as NSData))
}

private func digest(input : NSData) -> NSData {
    let digestLength = Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
    var hashValue = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: digestLength)
    CC_SHA256(input.bytes, UInt32(input.length), &hashValue)
    return NSData(bytes: hashValue, length: digestLength)
}

private  func getHexString(fromData data: NSData) -> String {
    var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: data.length)
    data.getBytes(&bytes, length: data.length)

    var hexString = ""
    for byte in bytes {
        hexString += String(format:"%02x", UInt8(byte))
    }
    return hexString
}}
```

**How to Use it**

```
let signatures = "yourStringToBeConverted".get_sha256_String()
```

also don't forgot to import `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>` in your **Bridging-Header.h**