# Generate SHA256 String in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sha256

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sha256 in Objective-C for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709204/sha256-in-objective-c-for-iphone)

Greetings,

I'm having terrible trouble generating a SHA256 string in Objective C (probably because I'm so new to the language).

In jQuery, all I have to do is this:

```
var sha256String=$.sha256("Hello");
```

which produces the hash as expected.

But in Objective-C, I've tried the following to no avail:

```
NSString *pword=[[NSString alloc]
initWithString:login_pword.text];
unsigned char result[64];
CC_SHA256([pword UTF8String], [pword lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],result);
UIAlertView *msg=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hi" message:result delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[msg show];
[msg release];
```

Is there some function that I can call such as:

```
NSString *sha256String=[self getSHA256:pword];
```

This is what I'm trying to create and I'm finding it very difficult!

I hope someone can help.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: I certainly hope you aren't expecting any behavioral similarities between Javascript and Objective-C.

Comment: I've seen that thread already thanks. I'm trying to return the sha256 string.

Comment: The linked question is not an exact duplicate. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `result` into the `UIAlertView`'s `init` method. `result` is a `char[]`, and `UIAlertView` expects an `NSString*`. You need to convert your `char[]` to an `NSString *`.

Try this:

```
NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithCString:result encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
UIAlertView *msg=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hi" message:resultString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Also see [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/hashvalue-object-for-holding-md5-and.html) article on hashing on the iPhone.

Comment: Hey, I did that, but I get gobbldy-gook on the result. It looks like UTF8, when in fact I want it base64 encoded...

Comment: Well you aren't Base64 encoding the result data anywhere in the code you posted. Have you tried doing that first? And again, read the article I posted the link to. It is for MD5 hashing but mentions adjustments you have to make for SHA256.

Answer (score 56):

After much playing around today, I finally came up with a function to get the SHA256:

```
-(NSString*) sha256:(NSString *)clear{
    const char *s=[clear cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSData *keyData=[NSData dataWithBytes:s length:strlen(s)];

    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH]={0};
    CC_SHA256(keyData.bytes, keyData.length, digest);
    NSData *out=[NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    NSString *hash=[out description];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    return hash;
}
```

This gives the same output as PHP. It can easily be converted to SHA1 - just change 'SHA256' to 'SHA1'.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: making your code depend on `description` seem like a very bad idea to me. Description is not meant to be machine readable but only for debugging.

Comment: how can i use this with a key , i mean let say i have string and key  ,

Comment: What's CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH? Got it - need to `#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>`

Comment: This is a bad answer as you should never rely on description to process information. Description provides information for debugging purposes only, classes override the default NSObject method (that prints the memory address of the object) to provide useful information for debugging. A change on what this method actually does can happen at any time without notice.

Comment: Swift 3 format?

Comment: This answer works. But it's better to use `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:out encoding:NSASCIIStringENcoding]` instead of using `NSData`'s `description` and doing replacements. Also, naming a variable as `out` probably is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the OpenSSL C functions. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918676/generate-sha-hash-in-openssl) on how to do that. As input string, you'd use `[myString UTFString]` with length `[myString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`.